# Gradle: how to test custom task output (println)

Tags: java, gradle

How would I go about testing the `println` output of custom Gradle tasks? This is my code so far:

```
class TaskTest {
    @Test
    void testSomething() {
        Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
        def task = project.task('testTask', type: Task)
        task.execute()
        <<assert task did println "Hello, world!">>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using [SystemOutputInterceptor](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/ui/SystemOutputInterceptor.html) This should look something like this:

```
import groovy.ui.SystemOutputInterceptor

class TaskTest {
    @Test
    void testSomething() {
        def expected = 'expectedOutput'
        def actual ='';
        def interceptor = new SystemOutputInterceptor({ actual += it; false});

        Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
        def task = project.task('testTask', type: Task)

        interceptor.start()
        task.execute()
        interceptor.stop()

        assert actual.trim() == expected
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you would like to use [spock](https://code.google.com/p/spock/) for Your's than You could also test this like that:

```
class TaskTest extends spock.lang.Specification {
  def "should print test to stdout"() {
    given:
    def expected = 'expectedOutput'
    System.out = Mock(PrintStream)
    Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
    def task = project.task('testTask', type: Task)

    when:
    task.execute()

    then:
    1 * System.out.println(expected)
  }
}
```

mocking out `System.out` in Java should be possible with [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to replace standard output stream with your implementation and then read data from it. You can do it for error end input streams too.

```
def stdout = System.out
def os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

System.out = new PrintStream(os)
println 'Hello World!' // implicit flush

def array = os.toByteArray()
def is = new ByteArrayInputStream(array)
System.out = stdout

def line = is.readLines()[0]
assert line == 'Hello World!'
```